# Prove that, given two chords on circle O labeled AB and CD, and given that arc AC and arc BD are equal, that AB=CD

Tags: geometry, circles

Prove that, given two chords on circle $O$ labeled $AB$ and $CD$, and given that arcs $AC$ and arc $BD$ are equal, then $AB\parallel CD$.

[image]

I understand that they are parallel, but I need help forming a proof to prove it. 
Thanks!

Comment: Um, that picture is an *entirely* different question.

Comment: Can you restate your question- because there is contradictory information here.

Comment: Um, what methods do we have for measuring arc lengths?  Connect the chords to the circle center.  These form concurrent trinags.  Thus the interior angles are the same.  Ivm assuming arc length corresponding to interior angle is somehow introduced as an axion somehow.

Comment: Oh, I just reread your post.  AB is NOT equal to CD.  AB is parellel to CD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are hints for two different ways to prove it.

Hint 1: Draw $BC$, and think about the angles $ABC$ and $BCD$.

Hint 2: Draw a diameter through the midpoint of $CD$.  Think about what happens when you reflect the picture across this diameter.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured it out.